# Is there another way in python to remove a key,value pair from a dictionary other than del key[value]?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a function that works fine on its own, but raises a key error when I try to use it inside another function. Rather than try to explain the larger context, I thought it would be easier to just change the *del hand[letter]*, which is where the error is raised. In some cases I could just change hand[letter] to hand.get(letter,None), but I can't use this with the del operator, it throws an error. Any ideas?

```
hand = {'r': 2, 'a': 3, 'p': 2, 'e': 1, 't': 1, 'u':1}
word = 'rapture'

def update_hand(hand, word):
"""This function loops through letters, and if the letter is in the \
hand, it reduces the corresponding int value by one, until there is \
no longer that letter in the hand, then it deletes the key,value pair \
all together"""
    letters = set(word)
    for letter in letters:
        if letter in hand.keys():
            hand[letter] = hand[letter]-1
        if hand[letter] <= 0:
            del hand[letter]
    return hand
```

Comment: try the `pop` dictionary member function

Answer (score 5):

Use `.pop`, so in the case the key does not exist, it does not throw any error when you use a default, say `None`:

```
hand.pop(letter, None)
#                  ^ pops None when the key letter does not exist
```

Since you already have a check for the existence of the same key in one of your `if` conditions, you can simply do:

```
for letter in letters:
    if letter in hand: # same as letter in hand.keys()
         hand[letter] = hand[letter] - 1
         if hand[letter] <= 0:
             hand.pop(letter, None) # del hand[letter] should not throw errors in this case
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function "works fine on it's own but raises when called from another function" then the very first thing to do would be to find out *why* you have a problem in the second case. Else it's a canonical example of [programming by accident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation) - which we all know never work in the long term.

Now there's an obvious cause for a `KeyError` in your function's code, which doesn't depends on anything else that the function's inputs: you try to delete a key without checking it's existence first (the `if hand[letter] <= 0:` statement). Try passing an empty dict for the `hand` param and you'll find out your function does *not* "works fine on it's own".

Comment: The function is meant to assume that the hand param has the all the letters in the word param. I have another function that checks to make sure the word is valid, i.e. That the word is both in the word list and composed only of letters in hand. The functions passed the unit tests, which were written by programmers much more experienced than myself. I didn't include that because people are so picky about questions here. Interesting things happen when I try to put them together. Thank you for your feedback, I'll look into it.